# Responsive iframe - width 100%

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to embed a vimeo iframe with `100% width`.
If I try like that it is not getting the full width:

```
<iframe title="vimeo-player" src=" <?php echo $src; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If I use suggested answers in similar questions then the iframe is dissapeared:

```
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```

Here is the link https://kappagram.tk/work/bookoo/ with fixed height but its not what I want because in smaller screens there is a blank space...

Answer (score 0):

The div with the id #gallery and it's parent section both have small padding on the sides (left & right). By removing those paddings (I've used the Google Dev Tools to test it), the width cover the whole width,

Width 100% means 100% of it's parents width, but also with it's margin and padding.

I would suggest giving the width a relative length unit such as 'vw'. You can read more about relative length unit in CSS over here: [W3Schools documents on CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php)

Comment: but I need those paddings... I need to be the same width with underneath elements